# redireccionamiento a un id con html etiqueta <a>

Tags: html, redirección

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs " >
    <li class="tab " title="Para empezar"><a class="active" href="#swipe-1" >    Para empezar</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Datos a tomar en cuenta "><a  href="#swipe-2">Datos a tomar en cuenta </a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Recuerda que"><a  href="#swipe-3">Recuerda que</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Cambia tu contraseña"><a  href="#swipe-4">Cambia tu contraseña</a></li>
  </ul>




  <div id="swipe-1" align="center">
<section >

<br>
<br>
<img src="imagenesayuda/pregunta.jpg" class="alineadoTextoImagenCentro" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
<pre> ¿Por qué necesitas cambiar tu contraseña?<pre>

<a style="color:black;" href="swipe-2"  >Porque se me olvidó </a>
<a style="color:black;" href="swipe-2"  >Porque se me olvidó </a>
<a style="color:black;" href="swipe-2"  >Porque se me olvidó </a>


</section>
</div>

  <div id="swipe-2">
<section>
 22222222222
</section>
</div>



  <div id="swipe-3">
<section>
 33333333333
</section>
</div>
```

estoy tratando de que  al presionar uno de los datos "porque se me olvido" me dirija a la segunda pantalla

"datos a tomar en cuenta"

cuando presiono sobre datos a tomar en cuenta si me muestra el segundo div con la informacion que tengo alli.

Quiciera saber por que si me sirve con el  al colocarle el href="#swipe-1" no me sirve con el  href="#swipe-1".

Comment: Falta el `#` al principio de los 3 href "Porque se me olvidó".

Comment: cuando le coloco "#swipe-3" no me manda a la seccion , me deja en el url , el nombre de la carpeta +#swipe-3
http://localhost/helpdesk/changuepasss.php#swipe-3

Comment: Para lo que quieres hacer se necesita Javascript. Te recomiendo que no reinventes la rueda y utilices algo ya existente, como los [Tabs de Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs).